# What is equivalent Dagger's @Named in Koin?

Tags: kotlin, koin

I'm in the process to moving app from Dagger2 to Koin and need to convert below dagger's

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("refresh")
fun provideRefreshRetrofit(@Named("refresh") okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, gson: Gson): Retrofit {/*...not important...*/}
```

till now:

```
single<Retrofit> { /*....*/ }
```

but I need to have similar entry in same module. Is a way to convert/solve/workaround it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [docs](https://insert-koin.io/docs/1.0/quick-references/koin-dsl/#implicit-naming--namespaces). You can give a name to a definition

```
single(name="refresh") { Retrofit.Builder().build() }
```

and use it

```
factory { ClassThatDependsOnRefresh(get("refresh")) }
```

Just using single and factory as example here.